# How to make a payment for each product in an invoice in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have an invoice with 2 products (product A and B), I need to do a payment only for the product A, is there any way to do that ?, and after see the product A with the correct moves in the accounting.

I know how to do the change in code but will be better if Odoo has this functionality

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> That can be done if you shipped all products separately and keep
>   invoice policy based on shipment. Then you can create separate invoice
>   for each products.

[image]

While you click on Create Invoice button in sales order then it will create invoice for eligible shipments with it's all delivered products.

So your purpose will be resolved by just change the configuration other there is no more option in odoo you have to write code to achieve it.